# How to run Java from R?

Tags: r, rjava

I would like to run java from R.
I wrote the following code:

```
install.packages("rJava")
library (rJava)

PARA<-'AA'
PARB<-'BB'
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath('C:/ATD/SO.jar -t')
f<-J (PARA, PARB)
```

Where PARA and PARB are characters.

I get the following error:

```
Error in .jfindClass(o) : class not found
```

From command line I run the following:

```
C:> CD ATD
C:\ATD> SO -t AA BB
```